# Is it a code smell to have to query a dictionary for a key whose value matches some criteria?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I am working on a `ChildModelListSheetHandler`, that has a `childModelListDict`.

As what you're probably thinking, it maps the foreign keys that are the IDs of the parent models, to the list of child models associated with that parent model.

I start working on a derived class thereof: `RateCardChildModelListHandler`. So far, so good.

I get to the part where I have to implement how to write it into a row. This is where I start squirming...

The code is clean for the most part, except for writing the foreign key. It looks like:

```
    @Override
    protected void fillInRow(Row row, MembershipFeeStructureModel record) {
        Cell primaryKeyCell = row.getCell(this.primaryKeyCellIdx),
            foreignKeyCell = row.getCell(this.foreignKeyCellIdx),
            startDateCell = row.getCell(2),
            endDateCell = row.getCell(3),
            enrollmentStartDateCell = row.getCell(4),
            enrollmentEndDateCell = row.getCell(5),
            annualAmountCell = row.getCell(6),
            annualDiscountCell = row.getCell(7);
        
        if (SMDSpreadsheetUtils.IsRowEmpty(row)) { 
            primaryKeyCell = row.createCell(this.primaryKeyCellIdx);
            foreignKeyCell = row.createCell(this.foreignKeyCellIdx);
            startDateCell = row.createCell(2);
            endDateCell = row.createCell(3);
            enrollmentStartDateCell = row.createCell(4);
            enrollmentEndDateCell = row.createCell(5);
            annualAmountCell = row.createCell(6);
            annualDiscountCell = row.createCell(7);
        }
        
        primaryKeyCell.setCellValue(record.getId());

        // this line right here...
        foreignKeyCell.setCellValue((int)this.childModelListDict.find { int key, List<MembershipFeeStructureModel> value ->
            return (value.find { MembershipFeeStructureModel childModel -> return childModel.getId() == record.getId() } != null)
        }.key);

        startDateCell.setCellValue(SMDDateUtils.ToDateString(record.getStartDate()));
        endDateCell.setCellValue(SMDDateUtils.ToDateString(record.getEndDate()));
        enrollmentStartDateCell.setCellValue(SMDDateUtils.ToDateString(record.getEnrollmentStartDate()));
        enrollmentEndDateCell.setCellValue(SMDDateUtils.ToDateString(record.getEnrollmentEndDate()));
        annualAmountCell.setCellValue(record.getAnnualFee());
        annualDiscountCell.setCellValue(record.getDiscountAmount());
    }
```

Is this necessarily a code smell, to have to **query the dictionary for a value condition**, or am I worrying for nothing?

Comment: To quote [Donald Knuth](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization):  *"Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."* - but does this code fall into the 97% or 3%?

Comment: What specific problem do you have with this code? "Worrying" is not a problem we can solve for you.

Comment: It's okay, but you don't get any speed advantage from the dictionary (you are treating it like a list). If that's okay here then it's okay here. I assume you need the dictionary most of the time, but not this time.

Comment: To be honest, @BenCottrell already answered your question. There is no point in worrying about performance. Measure first. Then assess whether this is a valid worry.